# What is the difference between "order" and "command"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between those two words `order` and `command`, and where to use each of them?

Please give some examples.

Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of differences, and lots of overlaps. Look them up in a dictionary.

Comment: Think of interchanging them. Would you issue your commands to a waiter in a restaurant? How about typing things into an order line on a computer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A question any dictionary answers. "order" and "command" have a common meaning, but they have different uses  as well.
"order" can refer to the arrangement of things as in "the order of letters in the alphabet". It can also be used in the economic area, a client can give an order to a dealer.
"order and command" can be used in the military area. In religion you speak of 
"The Ten Commandments" and "command" has a general sense as in "the command of language".